# ajax success redirect page and fill the from

Tags: javascript, ajax

JavaScript:

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit', function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("id");


    $.ajax({
        url:"/fatch",
        method:'get',
        data:{FileId:id},
        dataType:'json',
        success:function(data)
        {

            location.href = "/edit";
            alert(data.fname); // it's working 
            $('#fname').val(data.fname); // didn't work 

        }
    })
});
```

View page:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">
                            <label>Father Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control has-feedback-left" placeholder="Father Name" name="fname" id="fname"required>
                            <span class="fa fa-file form-control-feedback left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        </div>
```

JavaScript runs on `/fatch` page. I want to fill father name in `/edit` page (JavaScript file included everywhere).

However, it doesn't fill the father name. Why is this occurring and how do I resolve it?

Comment: How it could work ? You have written location.href = "/edit"; in success callback, that redirect your page to different location, The code written after this line is useless since page get reloaded.

Comment: Then , How to fill you have any idea @R.K.Saini

Comment: I don't know what you want to achieve here, Why you fetching data in a different page while you need to fill data in another page. Just Make ajax call on the page where you need the data. Although you can use query string to pass your data to different page

Answer (score 0):

Should work, do you have multiple fname fields in the code please verify. Or use this

```js
console.log($('input[name="fname"]'))
$('input[name="fname"]').each(function(i){
  console.log(this)
  $(this).val(Math.random()+"iota")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">
                            <label>Father Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control has-feedback-left" placeholder="Father Name" name="fname" id="fname"required>
                            <span class="fa fa-file form-control-feedback left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">
                            <label>Father Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control has-feedback-left" placeholder="Father Name" name="fname" id="fname"required>
                            <span class="fa fa-file form-control-feedback left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        </div>
```

Comment: can you share the log of JSON received and the log of each function? As said by @R.K.Saini is the answer. Remove the line of relocation and just insert the data.